# Convert TimeSpan to Int

Tags: c#, asp.net, casting, int, timespan

I have a `Vacation` table which consists of three columns as following:

Balance       varchar(20), 
National_ID   varchar(15), 
NoOfDays      varchar(20),

I use this code to update table values:

```
protected void btnadd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TimeSpan remaindate;
        DateTime start = DateTime.Parse(tbstartvaca.Text).Date;
        DateTime end = DateTime.Parse(tbendvaca.Text).Date;
        TimeSpan vacation = TimeSpan.Parse(lbldays.Text);
        TimeSpan total;
        if (start > end)
        {
            lberr.Text = "Please check again on Starting date";
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            remaindate = end - start;
            lberr.Text = "you have left with " + remaindate.TotalDays + "days.";
            total = vacation - remaindate;
            lbldays.Text = "you have left with " + total.TotalDays + "days.";
            s = "Update Vacation set Balance = '" + total + "', NoOfDays ='" + remaindate + "' where National_ID = '" + lblid.Text+ "'";
            if (db.Run(s))
            {
                //lberr.Text = "The data has update";
            }

            else
            {
                lberr.Text = "The data has not update";
            }
        }

    }
```

How can I change the type of data from `TimeSpan` to `integer` with variable and total after calculated formula to save a value in the table as int?

Please note that I changed the type of values to varchar(20) with Balance and NoOfDays to make the project work.

Comment: Maybe this question will make sense to someone else, but `"How can I change type of data from TimeSpan to integer with variable and total after calculated formula to save a value in the table as int."` makes absolutely no sense to me. You should try and revise this question with more detail.

Comment: What is the problem in just casting your days into `int`? `var days = (int) total.TotalDays;`

Comment: The problem when I update the value in the table for balance and NoOfDays the values appear like this 20:00:00 or 30:00:00. My question how can save the value as integar to be the value like 30 or 20.

Comment: Please consider using parameters instead of building a value into a sql command string. Look up "sql injection". It would also prevent formatting issues

Answer (score 2):

First of all I would suggest to set Balance and NoOfDays type back to int. It only adds unnecessary complexity to your program for string parsing, wastes space etc...

For your question the simplest thing to do (as others suggested), is to just cast the total variable to int directly:

```
int days = (int)total.TotalDays;
```

Answer (score 1):

Well if you are taking a specific value from .net you get an int.
For example for the days. What particular value of timespan do you want?

For example:

```
TimeSpan g = TimeSpan.MinValue;
int p = g.Days;
```

In your code you seem to understand that concept.
I do not think you are able to convert a Timespan to Integer.

Please edit your question, so we can understand better

Answer (score 0):

Try change your DB-query to this:
`"Update Vacation set Balance = " + total.TotalDays + ", NoOfDays = " + remaindate.TotalDays + " where National_ID = '" + lblid.Text + "'"`